# Java GUI freeze when clicking jButton

Tags: java, swing

this is my Java GUI first try i don't know which one is error. When i press jbutton my GUI stuck.
Please assist

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package latihancrud;

import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author agungmahaputra
 */
public class menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form menu
     */
    public menu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtNIS = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtAddress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtEmail = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtJurusan = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("NIS");

        jLabel2.setText("Data Siswa");

        jLabel3.setText("Nama");

        jLabel4.setText("Jurusan");

        jLabel5.setText("Alamat");

        jLabel6.setText("Email");

        jButton2.setText("Edit");

        jButton3.setText("Add");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Delete");

        jButton6.setText("Clear");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(187, 187, 187)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtEmail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtAddress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtNIS, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtJurusan, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton6))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(txtNIS, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(txtName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(txtAddress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(txtEmail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(txtJurusan, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(262, 262, 262)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(298, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tbStudent VALUES ('"+txtNIS.getText()+"','"+txtName.getText()+"','"+txtAddress.getText()+"','"+txtEmail.getText()+"','"+txtJurusan.getText()+"')";
        java.sql.Connection conn=(Connection)connection.configDB();
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sukses menambahkan data");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }


    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new menu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtAddress;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtEmail;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtJurusan;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtNIS;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtName;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Read about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). This topic will help you to understand what's wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in my comment, you need to read the article about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). To solve your freezing problem you need to move your code that calls database operations in another thread. The best way to do it is to use `SwingWorker`. Here is how it will look in your code

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql = "INSERT INTO tbStudent VALUES ('"+txtNIS.getText()+"','"+txtName.getText()+"','"+txtAddress.getText()+"','"+txtEmail.getText()+"','"+txtJurusan.getText()+"')";
    java.sql.Connection conn=(Connection)connection.configDB();
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
        private String message;
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try {
                return pst.execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = e.getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            if (get()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sukses menambahkan data");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(menu.this, message);
            }
        }

    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

I've not tested this solution. If it doesn't work, please let me know.